# Views of world during insight meditation

Tags: meditation-insight

I am reading books on Buddhism and I come across this sentence in every book.

**It states that our world view will change and we will know actual working of the world during insight meditation.**

It doesn't provide any explanation on how  different it is / will be from the view which I have. Whether this actual view of world is same for everyone who does insight meditation or it is different based on the experience one has?

What is difference between these two views?

Comment: How can a book know what view you currently have?

Comment: One who reads a book knows his views and how it differs from the view mentioned in the book. So I want to know what is that view to which my current view differs and will change to.

Comment: Then you would need to begin the practice of insight meditation and find out first hand.

Comment: I didn't understand the last question, which two views? May you clarify it?

Comment: @eric - I have my views of the world and you have your views of the world based on the experiences we encountered. Now during insight meditation, this view changes. How it changes is my query and their differences.

Comment: @eric - I have my views of the world and you have your views of the world based on the experiences we encountered. Now during insight meditation, this view changes. How it changes is my query and their differences.

Comment: @eric - I have my views of the world and you have your views of the world based on the experiences we encountered. Now during insight meditation, this view changes. How it changes is my query and their differences.

Answer (score 2):

It's a moment by moment view of our own individual experience. You know the workings of your imediate experience more and more the more you practice seeing reality as it is. Seeing reality as it is means putting more focus on whatever you're aware of on purpose, in your own experiencial reality, moment by moment. This is basically insight meditation or mindfulness.

When you understand your own world of experience then you know the rest of the world because it all works fundamentally the same. Approached another way, your experience is the world for you as my experience is my world for me.-Metta

Comment: Then our worlds are different based on our experience.

Comment: @8CK8 Yes and no. Really , ultimatley, there is no "our world" but just experience moment by moment but conceptually there is "our world". Ultimately there is no future or past so any memories or knowlege about "our world" and things that happened in the past or will happen in the future that you or I have are just  experiences in the present moment,  thought experiences  in the present moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your world view changes when you become [Sotāpanna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sot%C4%81panna). I.e. you have understood [dependent origination (DO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prat%C4%ABtyasamutp%C4%81da) and [4 Noble Truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Noble_Truths) and [Ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avidy%C4%81_(Buddhism)) is no more hence you [see things as they are](http://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/yath%C4%81-bh%C5%ABta-%C3%B1%C4%81na-dassana/index.html). The difference is that before you [mind had Ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moha_(Buddhism)), i.e., you had a mind with Ignorance and [Delusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moha_(Buddhism)) and subsequently becomes a that is a [mind without Ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoha) due to the paradigm shift when you perfectly understand [DO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prat%C4%ABtyasamutp%C4%81da) and the [4 Noble Truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Noble_Truths). When you reach the final goal your mind is rootless or without [mental influxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_marks_of_existence) or broken from the [fetters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetter_(Buddhism)) or devoid of [Defilements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleshas_(Buddhism)). In understanding the [DO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prat%C4%ABtyasamutp%C4%81da) and the [4 Noble Truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Noble_Truths) the [3 Marks of Existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_marks_of_existence) is instrumental.

Answer (score 0):

When one does not practice insight meditation ones world view is subjective and not in line with reality. One has no reference point so to say.

When one is practicing insight meditation one sees for oneself how reality functions and delusion is done away with, e.g. the illusion of permanence and an enduring Self-entity.

An enduring Self-entity can also be called a Self, Me, Soul etc. There is no such thing which is verifiable through the practice of insight meditation. What is believed to be a Self is merely a mental formation.

When practicing insight meditation one will see how conditioned phenomena are not stand alone units. They have causes and conditions and they themselves become causes for the arising of other phenomena. The relational factor and interdependency of conditioned phenomena becomes visible to the insight meditator.

Comment: Pl. explain about enduring Self-entity.

Comment: I would like the answer from one who is practicing insight meditation to tell about how reality functions.

Comment: @8CK8. Answer updated.